# why my flag is marked as disputed?

Tags: discussion

not sure why my flag is marked as disputed for [Magento 2 - How to add ajax tab on admin user edit page in admin section](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/122396/magento-2-how-to-add-ajax-tab-on-admin-user-edit-page-in-admin-section/155248#155248) . Its not an answer but still my flag is marked as disputed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rahul Makwana, Thanks for raising the concern about the flag.

The answer is not an answer, So right now I am deleting.

Your flag is disputed by Community user means which is a background process.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=profile

Answer (score 1):

The flag was disputed because the community has a mixed feeling about the post.

From [the review](https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/145712), 1 "Recommend Deletion", but 2 "Looks OK". Thus, the consensus was that the post deemed "OK" even though it was flagged as "Not an Answer".

From [What is a disputed flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/95277),

> Currently, the following scenarios result in a flag being disputed:
>
> - [...]
> - A "not an answer" or "very low quality" flag kicks the post into the Low Quality Posts review queue but the final result of the review was "Looks OK".